# How to add types d.ts incrementally to my js library?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, tsc

I am building a library written in pure javascript. I was asked to create types for consumers that are using the library from typescript projects. The library is a little bit extensive so they are happy for me to provide the definition for only the most used functions.

I did exactly that with the most used functions in "types/index.d.ts"... but now
I am struggling to get the configuration right for my package.json.

1.- adding at package.json

```
{
  ...
  "types": "types/index.d.ts",
  ...
}
```

works for my consumers in typescript so they get autocompletion in vscode but fails to them when compiling a typescript that tries to import a missing function in the types/index.d.ts

```
import {superFetch} from 'aweJsTurbo'

types/index.d.ts TS2305: Module '"aweJsTurbo"' has no exported member superFetch
```

Interestingly, it generates js code that work perfectly (as it is able to import the right javascript).

2.- removing from package.json "types": "types/index.d.ts", makes the tsc compiler works but they lose autocompletion.

I would have thought that there should be a way to remove the annoying compilation errors for types declaration for which there is an actual implementation in javascript.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> fails to them when compiling a typescript that tries to import a missing function'

The whole point of Typescript is to ensure type safety, so this is expected behavior.

You might want to look at approaches like [this one](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/dts-from-js.html) to ease the burden of maintaining the `*.d.ts` file for a large codebase, though. I haven't tried it, but wager if you provide even the simplest JSDoc for all of your API methods, it will generate reasonable TS  declarations you can then incrementally improve upon.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The compiler doesn't complain about missing some types here and then. I thought types were preferable but optional and you could incorporate them gradually. I think I will follow the autogeneration approach you mention if no one is coming with a solution for the problem.